# Fetch hls url from dynamo table in Aws MediaConvert

Tags: php, android, ios, amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

We have configured the media convert service in S3 bucket. From mobile application we are uploading the video file to S3 bucket. In php backend we are storing the file name and path   for eg uploads/post_media/1058826857.mov . Here uploads/post_media/ is the s3 folder and 1058826857.mov is the file name.

When the upload is successful we are querying the Dynamo DB to get the .hls format of the uploaded video in PHP code. We are querying the Dynamo DB by  attribute "srcVideo". In dynamo table we can see that column srcVideo has same filepath as "uploads/post_media/1058826857.mov" and the HLS entry exist in the table.

The issue that we are facing is that when we are querying the dynamo table from PHP code we are using srcVideo as attribute to query the table but we are not able to fetch the result and hls url .  But its entry exist is the dynamo DB.

We can query the dynamo table from ios and android as well. Please suggest the function and process if available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to share a snippet of the php code you are using to query the table?

There are also some php code examples / tutorials for querying DynamoDB available:

PHP and DynamoDB : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.html

AWS Code Sample -Query.php :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-dynamodb-Query.php.html